# How to list the second edition of a book

Tags: publications, mathematics, postdocs, cv, books

If an author has published a second edition of a book and he is in his earlier career stage as a mathematician, how do you recommend to include this second edition into the list of publications appearing e.g. in the CV? For example, should it be mentioned at all? Should it replace the first edition? Should both editions be listed, in particular when the second edition is a massive revision and 20 pages longer?

Comment: I can't imagine there's any rules about this, but presumably if someone reading your CV were to see a book listed amongst your publications which was marked as the second edition, they would assume you had been involved in the first edition as well. Listing multiple editions of the same book could also give the impression that you're trying to pad out your CV.

Comment: @Ian_Fin: I agree that typically one should only list the most recent edition.  But it does sometimes happen that, say, Author A wrote the first edition by herself, and then Author B joins the project to work on the second edition.  So B was involved in the second edition but not the first.  Sometimes this happens for textbooks that continue to be revised long after the original author has retired or died.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's true. As I was writing that I did think of several multi-edition textbooks whose original authors have long-since surrendered the reigns. Perhaps a sensible default would be to only list the most recent edition you were involved with, and include a note if you weren't involved in one or more preceding edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you would just give the bibliographic information for the most recent edition.  If you feel it's important to say when you first wrote it, you could add a parenthetical like *(First edition published in 1987)*.

If the book was originally written by someone else, and you joined as a co-author on a later edition, then include a note like *(Co-author for editions 5 and later)*.

This would be the same regardless of what stage of your career you are at, and as far as I know it would be the same in any field.